# Creating a webpage crawler that finds and maches user input

Tags: java, php, python, html, mysql

I made a website with many pages, on each page is a sample essay. The homepage is a page with a search field. I'm attempting to design a system where a user can type in a word and when they click 'search', multiple paragaphs containing the searched word from the pages with a sample essays are loaded on to the page.

I'm 14 and have been programming for about 2 years, can anyone please explain to me the programming languages/technologies I'll need to accomplish this task and provide suggestions as to how I can achieve my task.

All I have so far are the web pages with articles and a custom search page I've made with PHP. Any suggestions?

Comment: We are not here to recommend for/against any particular language/product/library. In the end, they're just opionions, and opinions are explicitly off-topic.

Comment: Marc, what does "opionions" mean http://prntscr.com/8n01p4 ?  And I just need to know where I can start as for most projects I can do myself but this is my hardest so far. I just need suggestions, SO has lots of talented people so I don't think this will be hard for them?

Comment: opinions, sorry. And like I said, we're not here to tell you how to do your project, or what to use. That's your job. You write some code, and we'll (maybe) help fix it.

Comment: You're wanting to know whether to use java, php, or python? Whichever one you know best. They can all do this. Sounds to me like it would be easy if you store your page text in the db, then you don't even need a crawler, just a query with `like`.

Comment: Thanks developerwjk, didn't think of that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The programing language does not realy matter for the way to solve the problem. You can implement it in the language which you are comfortable with.

There are two basic ways to solve the problem:

1. Use a crawler which creates a index of words found on the different pages
   The use that index to lookup the searched word

or

2. When the user has entered the search expression, you start crawling the pages and look if the search expression is found

Of course both solutions will have different (dis)advantages

For example:
In 1) you need to do a inital crawl (and udate it later on when the pages change)

In 1) you need to store the crawl result in some sort of database

In 1) you will receive instanst search results

In 2) You don't need a database/datastore

In 2) You will have to wait until all pages are searched before showing the final resultlist

Comment: What if I wanted to crawl a large website like yooutube to get video stats, could I use the same method?

Comment: I would first look if youtube don't have a api to query such things. But basically yes, it would work that way too (Unless the robots.txt file disallows you to crawl the site)